# Make DataGridView resort after data changed programatically

Tags: datagridview

I have DataGridView element with users allowed to sort it by click in any column header.

I noticed that when I programmatically add rows to the grid they always go to the end of the grid no matter what sort order is chosen.

Is it possible to make grid keep itself sorted according to the user selection all the time - even after programmatic data changes.

I use it in unbound mode.

Answer (score 2):

Need something like this:

```
if(grid.SortOrder != SortOrder.None && grid.SortedColumn != null)
{
  ListSortDirection dir = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
  if(grid.SortOrder == SortOrder.Descending) dir = ListSortDirection.Descending;
  grid.Sort(grid.SortedColumn, dir);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep a button to refresh the datagrid after you add a data .. write the following code on button click event

e.g, table adapter = student_DetailsTableAdapter , 
dataset and table = sAHSDataSet1.Student_Details

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.student_DetailsTableAdapter.Fill(this.sAHSDataSet1.Student_Details);
        dataGridView1.Refresh();
    }
```